# Want to use pure css masonary grid layout just for 1 fullscreen div

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, css-grid

I am using this gallery grid layout

```
http://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/pvamyK
```

html:

```
<section id="photos"></section>
```

css:

```
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;

   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

I need the images to fill just a full screen div and the images that wont be covered in the screen can be cropped out. Right now the situation is that if the images don't fit the screen, it goes to the next column in the grid thus leaving large empty spaces at the end of each column.

I am using 25 images to fill a 5 column grid and without the full screen div, the grid would just extend for 3 screens. I just want 1 full screen div even if it means that many of the images wont be visible and will be cut off.

Comment: Your codepen doesn't seem to have the problem you describe. Are you asking how to disable scrolling?

Comment: check my answer, let me know what do you think?

Comment: @4castle I want the images to fit only 1 full screen. height: 100%. Right now, the images keep extending till the end of all images

Comment: @DanielH It is not working in my code. The following is my code 

html:

'<body>
<div class="letter">
  <div id="photos">
  </div>
</div>
</body>'
css:
'.letter {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5 !important;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}'

Answer (score 0):

- added `position: fixed;` to container (wraper for all img) so your screen are fixed.
- I suggest use less column for mobie view (3~4), otherwise you need more than 25 images to show 1 full screen without blank/white space.

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/' + width + '/' + height + '" alt="pretty kitty">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);
```

```css
#photos {
   /* Prevent vertical gaps */
   line-height: 0;
   position: fixed;
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -webkit-column-gap:   0px;
   -moz-column-count:    5;
   -moz-column-gap:      0px;
   column-count:         5;
   column-gap:           0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count:         5;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count:         5;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count:         5;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
  -moz-column-count:    5;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  column-count:         5;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="letter">
  <section id="photos"></section>
</div>
```